# Issue with Selenium,Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have written the following.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
bot = webdriver.Firefox()
bot.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(config['username'])
```

When I am using send_keys and happen to be typing at the same instant, then what I typed is also added in the username.
How to avoid this?

Example:

I want to fill the username with "sandeep"
If at the same instant I press 'a', then the username becomes "sandeepa" or something equivalent.

Comment: I doubt that there would be a simple solution for that. Do you have to type when this script runs?

Comment: This seems more like a limitation of the OS/Browser and Selenium than an actual issue. As DeepSpace added, do you _need_ to type at the same time as the test is running?

Comment: I used it to download and sync some files so it would be running at the back and I am using a cron job to run it so the simple solution is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use executeScript method:

```
webdriver.execute_script("document.getElementById('username').setAttribute('value', 'Sandeep')")
```

`JavaScript` will do text insertion as single operation.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options:

1. Create hidden input send keys to it than perform copy/paste from hidden to visible input, after remove hidden input.
2. Hide input, than send_keys to it and after show it back.

Usefull links:

[Performing a copy and paste with Selenium 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750447/performing-a-copy-and-paste-with-selenium-2)

[WebDriver: add new element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176515/webdriver-add-new-element)